# MATLAB Plot P(X>x)

Tags: random-variables

Here is my MATLAB code to plot P(X>x) for an exponential r.v. for E(X) = 10. I am pretty certain that my calculations are correct. The plot looks weird. Can anyone help?

clear;
clc;
U=rand(1,100000);
lambda = 1/10;
expValue = -log(1-U)/lambda;
prob=exp(-lambda*expValue);
plot(U,log(prob));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add '.' in the last command:

plot(U,log(prob),'.');

Comment: Should the plot be a straight line?

Comment: the fact is the the points are not ordered, thus the resulting plot is just a weird line that makes a strange path :)

Comment: it makes a strange tour, but in fact it passes through the right points!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thank you. Will sort(U) instead of U inside the plot function make it a straight line?

Comment: @mookid the question was, namely, "can anyone help?" and I helped him. Frankly, I don't see the problem...

Comment: @user100503 yes, you can also sort the vector U before computing the vector prob

Comment: @Paglia : in my opinion, it sould have been a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the responses.

Comment: Here is my MATLAB code for the similar plot for Poisson. I think I am not computing P(X>x) correctly. Can anyone help? clear; clc; U=rand(1,100000); for i=1:numel(U) k = 0; lambda = 10; p = exp(-lambda); G = p; while U(i) > G p = (lambda*p)/(k+1); G=G+p; k=k+1; end X(i)=k; end disp(mean(X)) prob=exp(-lambda*X); plot(U,log(X), '.');